# Spring Boot EhCache returning stale data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, ehcache-3

If service been hit after data is been expired. It is returning the old data and then refresing the data in the second hit. This is causing service to fail.

```
    @Cacheable(value = "tokenCache", cacheManager = "springTokenCacheManager")
    public String getToken(PublicKey publicKey) {....}
```

Jcache manager bean:

```
@Bean
  public JCacheCacheManager springTokenCacheManager(
      @Qualifier("tokenCacheManager") CacheManager cacheManager) {
    return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
  }

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
  public CacheManager tokenCacheManager(
      TokenExpiryPolicy tokenExpiryPolicy, CacheEventLogger cacheEventLogger) {

    CacheEventListenerConfigurationBuilder cacheEventListenerConfiguration =
        CacheEventListenerConfigurationBuilder.newEventListenerConfiguration(
                cacheEventLogger,
                EventType.CREATED,
                EventType.UPDATED,
                EventType.EVICTED,
                EventType.EXPIRED,
                EventType.REMOVED)
            .unordered()
            .asynchronous();

    CacheConfiguration<PublicKey, String> cacheConfiguration =
        CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                PublicKey.class, String.class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(1))
            .withExpiry(tokenExpiryPolicy)
            .withService(cacheEventListenerConfiguration)
            .build();


    EhcacheCachingProvider provider =
        (EhcacheCachingProvider)
            Caching.getCachingProvider("org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider");

  
    CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();

    Cache<PublicKey, String> cache =
        cacheManager.createCache(
                TOKEN_CACHE, Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration));

    return cacheManager;
  }
```

**ExpiryPolicy**

```
@Component
public class TokenExpiryPolicy implements ExpiryPolicy<PublicKey, String> {

  @Override
  public Duration getExpiryForCreation(PublicKey key, String value) {
    Duration expiryDate = getExpiryDate(value);
    log.info("Token expires duration for creation {}", expiryDate);
    return expiryDate;
  }

  @Override
  public Duration getExpiryForAccess(PublicKey key, Supplier<? extends String> value) {
    Duration expiryDate = getExpiryDate(value.get());
    log.info("Token expires duration for access {}", expiryDate);
    return expiryDate;
  }

  @Override
  public Duration getExpiryForUpdate(
      PublicKey key, Supplier<? extends String> oldValue, String newValue) {
    Duration expiryDate = getExpiryDate(newValue);
    log.info("Token expires duration for update {}", expiryDate);
    return expiryDate;
  }

  private Duration getExpiryDate(String token) {
    Duration expiry = Duration.ZERO;
    try {
      DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(token);
      Date expiresAt = decodedJWT.getExpiresAt();
      log.info("Token expires at {}", expiresAt);
      Date currentDate = new Date();
      if (expiresAt.before(currentDate)) {
        log.info("Token expired {}", expiresAt);
      } else {
        expiry = Duration.ofMillis(expiresAt.getTime());
      }
    } catch (JWTDecodeException e) {
      log.error("Exception while decoding JWT token");
    }
    return expiry;
  }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
   [2023-04-12 15:29:08,014 XNIO-1 task-2] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.TokenExpiryPolicy - Token expires at Wed Apr 12 13:30:26 BST 2023
    [2023-04-12 15:29:08,014 XNIO-1 task-1] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.TokenExpiryPolicy - Token expires at Wed Apr 12 13:30:26 BST 2023
    [2023-04-12 15:29:08,015 XNIO-1 task-1] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.TokenExpiryPolicy - Token expired Wed Apr 12 13:30:26 BST 2023
    [2023-04-12 15:29:08,015 XNIO-1 task-2] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.TokenExpiryPolicy - Token expired Wed Apr 12 13:30:26 BST 2023
    [2023-04-12 15:29:08,016 XNIO-1 task-1] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.TokenExpiryPolicy - Token expires duration for access PT0S
    [2023-04-12 15:29:08,016 XNIO-1 task-2] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.TokenExpiryPolicy - Token expires duration for access PT0S

[2023-04-12 15:29:08,024 Ehcache [_default_]-4] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.CacheEventLogger - caching listener event: EXPIRED key: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
```

After this failed request, I see cache has been created again

[2023-04-12 15:32:18,726 Ehcache [*default*]-5] INFO  c.b.s.s.s.caching.CacheEventLogger - caching listener event: CREATED key: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits